# Android Dom Parsing, ArrayList and Activities

Tags: java, android, xml, dom, arraylist

first of all sorry for my bad english. 
I'm working on an Android project: I have to realize a simple Android app and now I try to explain my difficulties and what I have to do.
I have to parse a xml (using dom parsing) and visualize a List of archaeological sites. When I click on a site, I want to visualize another List with the contents of each site and after all I want to visualize the content.

How can I do this?

This is the XML parsed and I want to add another level to visualize the other list with the content(can I do this?):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lista>
    <riga>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>title1</title>
    <thumb_url>image1_url</thumb_url>
    </riga>
    <riga>
        <id>2</id>
        <title>title2</title>
    <thumb_url>image2_url</thumb_url>
    </riga>
</lista>
```

and this is the main class:

```
public class Lista extends Activity {
    // All static variables
    static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    };
//  static final String URL = "lista_principale.xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_RIGA = "riga"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listaElem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        //String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL

        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lista_principale);

        String xml=convertStreamToString(is);


        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_RIGA);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            listaElem.add(map);
        }


        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, listaElem);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {



            }
        });
```